Same error as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15000 on spark 3 but there is no resolution on the JIRA
While running a job on spark3, we have hit the same error as mentioned in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15000 . Tried removing cache() and show() as suggested in the issue description, but it did not resolve.
Has anyone come across similar problem and how did one resolve it?
